# Ruby: new hash from local variables

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a Hash from local variables (tossing out vars that don't exist).  Something like this:

```
foo = "bar"
baz = "qiz"

["foo", "baz", "nothing"].something_awesome

#=>
{"foo" => "bar", "baz" => "qiz"}
```

I've tried a bunch of different combinations from Array and Enumerable, but can't find the right combo.  Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would just do `{"foo" => foo, "bar" => bar}`, but that may be pragmatism (and not having a "full context") talking...

Comment: couldn't live foo and baz as key/values in a hash? Playing around with variables and evals is so unpleasant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on top of Jin's answer is a slightly more idiomatic version that swallows exceptions:

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :042 > foo, bar = 'bar', 'quz'
=> ["bar", "quz"] 
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :043 > %w(foo bar nothing).reduce({}) { |acc, item| acc[item] = eval(item) rescue nil; acc }.reject { |k, v| v.nil? }
=> {"foo"=>"bar", "bar"=>"quz"}
```

IMHO though `eval` should feel dirty/risky and you might want to reconsider your approach in general.

Answer (score 3):

This is a generic way of getting a hash from the local variables, you don't even need to know the names:

```
foo, bar = 'baz', 'qux'
local_names = binding.send(:local_variables)
locals = local_names.reduce({}) do |acc, v| 
  acc[v] = binding.eval(v.to_s) unless v == :_
  acc
end
p locals # {:foo => 'baz', :bar => 'qux'}
```

This will get you *all* the locals, so if you want you can filter the list before doing the reduce.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `eval`.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > foo = "bar"
 => "bar" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > baz = "qiz"
 => "qiz" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > ["foo", "baz", "nothing"].each { |x| puts eval(x) }
bar
qiz
NameError: undefined local variable or method `nothing' for main:Object
    from (irb):3:in `eval'
    from (irb):3:in `eval'
    from (irb):3:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):3:in `each'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/jin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Combine this with some form of [exception handling](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html) and you're good to go.

**Example:**

```
foo = "bar"
baz = "qiz"

local_vars = Hash.new(0)

["foo", "baz", "nothing"].each do |x|
  begin
    local_vars[x] = eval(x)
  rescue NameError
    puts "No local var named: " + x # No local var named: nothing
  end
end

puts local_vars # {"foo"=>"bar", "baz"=>"qiz"}
```